# python ImportError cannot import parent module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to understand Python's import structure and have created the following:

```
+-- prj
|    +-- __init__.py
|    +-- /moda
|    |   +-- __init__.py
|    |   +-- fa.py
|    +-- /prja
|    |   +-- __init__.py
|    |   +-- prjf.py
|    +-- /web
|    |   +-- __init__.py
|    |   +-- page.py
|
```

**fa.py**

```
from prj.web import page    
print("fa")
```

**prjf.py**

```
from prj.moda import fa   
from .moda import fa
print(dir(prj))
print('prj')
```

**page.py**

```
print("page")
```

however, running:

```
 $pwd
/home/user/test/prj
 $ python prja/prjf.py
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prja/prjf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from prj.moda import fa
  File "/home/user/test/prj/prja/prj.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name prj
```

But this doesn't make sense since the official python
[docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) clearly state

> When packages are structured into subpackages (as with the sound package in the example), you can use absolute imports to refer to submodules of siblings packages. For example, **if the module sound.filters.vocoder needs to use the echo module in the sound.effects package, it can use from sound.effects import echo.**

Also if in prjf i put the relative import first I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prja/prjf.py", line 1, in <module>
from .moda import fa
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

while the expected outcome would be no such package moda

It's a default python3 install on default ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried: `from ..prj.moda import fa`?

Comment: I get ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package